# After deleting all local files and downloaded repository from GitHub, I can't use git push

Tags: git, github

I deleted all files from my directory and restored them by downloading zip from github. Then I initialized git and set it to this repositroy and wanted to push it, but then I got this error:

> To https://github.com/kunokdev/food-social-app.git
>    ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/kunokdev/food-social-app.git'
>   hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
>   hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
>   hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>   hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
>   kunok@Kunok:~/dev/food-social-app$ git push

I even used `git pull origin master` and it just put alot of trash lines into my files which I had to delete. 
How do I push it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `git clone https://github.com/kunokdev/food-social-app.git` you don't need to download zip file

Comment: But what about changes I made after downloading zip?

Comment: copy your changes somewhere else and after `git clone` copy it back and overwrite files then you would have your changes that you can see via `git status` and `git diff` and then you could add and commit them as usual

Answer (score 2):

> I deleted all files from my directory and restored them by downloading zip from github.
>
> Then I initialized git and set it to this repository and wanted to push it, but then I got this error

**restored them by downloading zip** - When you download Zip you only download the latest content without those full history. When you try to push, Git find out that you **don't have the full history** so he reject the push. This is what the error message means.

Clone the repo again and the you will be able to push without any errors.

Comment: But what about my changes I created?

Comment: +1 on this answer for explaining the underlying details. @Kunok, if you clone instead of downloading a zip file, you will be able to push normally; for now, take the changed files from the changed zip, and paste them into the cloned repository, then commit and push.

Comment: Actually I just cloned it into project with changes and nothing was gone